# Azure AD Self Service Group Management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I would like Azure AD Group Owners to manage the membership of their own groups through the Azure portal. I would like to grant the minimum permissions required for group management.  I have added a user as the owner of a **non-**mail enabled, cloud-only Azure AD security group. The account is a guest account.  Under group settings, I have set

'Owners can manage group membership requests in the Access Panel' to 'Yes'

'Restrict access to Groups in the Access Panel' to 'No'

'Owners who can assign members as group owners in Azure portals' to 'All'

When this user logs in, they see the list of group members very briefly (less than a second) and then the error message, 'Access denied.  You do not have access.' appears.  I have verified this behavior across multiple accounts, computers, and browsers.  I have verified that I can access the Group Members page on my laptop on one account but cannot from a more restrictive account that is not a Global Admin.

What am I missing?

[image: Azure Self Service Group Management]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out as soon as I posted.  The [Azure AD App Portal](https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com) has a link to your groups.  Clicking that link to groups takes you to a page where you can manage group membership.